# What is the detailed mechanism for the steps of this question?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]
Detailed mechanism especially if the aldol condensation and Diels Alder reaction are occurring.

Answer (score 1):

The hydrogenation with palladium poisoned with lead will form the cis alkene from the acetylene. This will form a 1,3-diene. This is a reaction which occurs on the surface of the palladium which has been modified with lead. What will happen is that hydrogen will chemicially adsorb onto the palladium, this forms hydrogen atoms which will be on the surface. These will react with chemically bonded acetylenes to form a vinyl group which is bonded to the surface. The vinyl group will react with a second hydrogen atom thus forming a cis alkene. If you consider the reaction of RuHCl(CO)(PPh3)3 with acetylenes which have a D atom as the terminal hydrogen then it will make it clear why the product is a cis alkene.

I think that the reaction will be a coordination of the acetylene (alkyne) followed by a migotory insertion.

It is normal to do the Diel-Alder reaction under thermal conditions, but I know that the 1,3-diene can adsorb UV light. We have the problem of knowing what will happen next.

If we convert the 1,3-diene into a diradical using the UV light then it could react with the alkene (ethylene). This could then ring close to form 7-methyl-1,2,3,4,4a,5,6,7-octahydronaphthalene.

The exact example in the book does not appear in Reaxys, so I suspect that it may been made up by the author of the book rather than being a real reaction that someone has done somewhere.

If we assume instead that the reaction is a [2+2] reaction which will form a cyclobutane then I think that the product B will not be able to form any of the final choices.

Treatment of 7-methyl-1,2,3,4,4a,5,6,7-octahydronaphthalene with ozone followed by dimethyl sulfide will form 2-methyl-4-(2-oxocyclohexyl)butanal. This reaction is a bit complex, it will a pericyclic reaction forming a five membered ring which then undergoes further reactions to form a second five membered ring. The dimethyl sulfide is a reducing agent which forms the ketoaldehyde.

If we were to react this with a base and form the more thermodynamically favoured enolate using the ketone, before using the aldehyde to react with the anolate then we would have a spiro compound (1-hydroxy-2-methylspiro[4.5]decan-6-one) which is not one of the options. But if we deprotonate the aldehyde to form an enolate and then react this enolate with the ketone then we would get 7a-hydroxy-1-methyloctahydro-1H-indene-1-carbaldehyde which is option a. This also puts the isotope lable (*) in the right location in the molecule.

[image]